# Expand Addressfield Components in Views

Tags: views, entities

Situation :

1. I have added few more fields in user registration form using account settings->manage fields. The type of the field is cck address field.
2. I created a new view as json document, and I added that field to the view as well, but the problem is its not expanding it as the way I wanted. 
   What I mean is, I filled the user registration form address field as first name, last name, street etc etc. but I am either seeing the whole field in a single line under Address tag in json or just a tag like this `{"nodes":[{"node":{"name":"admin","field_address":"1"}}]}`
   but what I want is like this:

   {"nodes":[{"node":{"name":"admin","first_name":"xyz","last_name":"sdas","street":"ssdsf"}}]}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using https://drupal.org/project/addressfield module ?

Comment: Yes, thats the same. I tried using Location module as well, but its the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue with [Addressfield](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module. There is a long discussion [here](https://drupal.org/node/991834) regarding this issue. You can find two solution for it by the patch provided by some members.

- [This one](https://drupal.org/files/issues/additional_views_fieldformatter-991834-10.patch) works by field formatter modification.

If you apply this patch, add the address field to a view and then you will see in the Formatter drop down all the components of the address is listed. (where before it just said Default).

- [This one](https://drupal.org/files/addressfield-views_components-991834-57.patch) works by adding data by field_view_data.

If you apply this patch then you can add the addressfield component in the add field itself. You will have option to add by searching something like "Content:Address(COMPONENT MACHINE NAME)

Comment: but could this be done with Location module?

Comment: @mad_programmer Please post a separate question for Location components. Let me see it..

Answer (score 2):

Current version of Addressfield (7.x-1.0-beta5) supports displaying address components in views as separate fields.